# RhinoMock 3.5 Runtime error when running on .net

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm using Rhino Mock 3.5 for .Net Framework 2.0 and when I run this code I get a run time error.

**This is the code**

```
IFile fileInterface = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFile>();<br>
IUrlMapper urlMapper = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUrlMapper>();

// this is the line causing the run-time error<br>
HttpContextBase mockHttpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();

HttpRequestBase mockRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();

RhinoMocksExtensions.Stub<HttpContextBase,HttpRequestBase>(mockHttpContext, delegate(HttpContextBase ctx)
{
                                                               return ctx.Request;
                                                           }
).Return(mockRequest);


RhinoMocksExtensions.Stub(fileInterface, delegate(IFile f)
                 {
                     f.Exists(Arg<string>.Is.Anything);
                 }
).Return(true);


AspxReplacementResolver resolverToTest = new AspxReplacementResolver(mockHttpContext, fileInterface, urlMapper);
```

**This is the Error:**

```
TestCase 'TestMockingRhinoMock35.TestTestFixtures.Test1'
failed: System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'System.Web.RequestNotification' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'......
```

System.Web.RequestNotification is part of Framework 3.0 but I'm using Framework 2.0 and I referenced the specific Rhino Mocks 3.5 for Framework 2.0 dll.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

`HttpContextBase` doesn't exist in .Net framework 2.0.  It was added in a .dll called `System.Web.Abstractions`, and is only available if you've installed the .Net Framework 3.5, *as well as* Service Pack 1 for .Net Framework 3.5.

You'll have to target .net 3.5 if you want to mock this out.  If you're using a seperate assembly for testing, there's no reason you couldn't target your test assembly to 3.5 and leave your production application alone.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually you can add a reference to System.Web.Abstractions and use it within .Net 2.0; I've been using it successfully.

Now that I'm writing these tests I am getting this error, so I guess I'll have to target .net 3.5 for testing since I have a separate assembly.

Thanks again